# HTML - have cell content stretch across columns without changing column width

Tags: html, css

In a row in my table about the animal kingdom, The first cell is always populated (animal name). However, the rest of the cells are always populated or never populated together.

In the case the first cell is populated and the rest are not, i would like to add a text to the second cell that says notifies the person that there is no data for the rest of the cells. However, I would like this text to stretch across cells without modifying the column width.

What happens:

[image]

(Code here, copied from W3schools: https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-M_cZpWSfoiKoTZfZgC9)

What I want (badly cropped):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colspan` to merge the columns. See [HTML colspan Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_colspan.asp)

In your loop you can check if there is empty data and apply the colspan.

`<td colspan="2"></td>`

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td colspan="2">Long text saying that the contact and country information are unavailable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```